# Haskell: Splitting list into tuple of two new lists

Tags: list, haskell, split

I am having difficulty figuring out how to split a list of Ints into a tuple containing two new lists, such that every element (starting with first) goes into the first list and every other element in the second.

Like so:

```
split [] = ([],[])
split [1] = ([1],[])
split [1,2] = ([1],[2])
split [1,2,3] = ([1,3],[2])
split [1,2,3,4] = ([1,3],[2,4])
```

I'm trying to accomplish this recursively(with guards) and only using the single argument xs

This is my approach that keeps getting error messages:

```
split :: [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
split xs | length(xs) == 0 = ([],[])
         | length(xs) == 1 = (xs !! 0 : [],[])
         | length(xs) == 2 = (xs !! 0 : [], xs !! 1 : [])
         | otherwise = (fst ++ xs !! 0, snd ++ xs !! 1) ++ split(drop 2 xs))
```

Comment: You should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `split` function returns a pair, but in the last case you are using `++` on the result of `split`.  That will be a type error, since `++` works on lists, not pairs.  There is also a type error because `fst` and `snd` are functions to pick out the elements of a pair, but you are using them is a strange way.

Furthermore, use pattern matching instead of using length.  Also, the case where you test if the length is 2 is not needed, since the general case removes 2 elements which takes you down to the base case of the empty list.

You can also make your function more general by using a type variable `a` instead of `Int` in the type.

[Edit]: Added code

```
split :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
split [] = ([], [])
split [x] = ([x], [])
split (x:y:xys) = (x:xs, y:ys) where (xs, ys) = split xys
```

Comment: Alternatively, `split (z:zs) = (z:ys, xs) where (xs, ys) = split zs`!

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this is with mutual recursion. It comes out very easy to read:

```
split xs = (odds xs, evens xs)

odds (x:xs) = x : evens xs
odds xs     = []

evens xs = odds (drop 1 xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
split :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
split xs | null xs = ([], [])
         | otherwise = (head xs : snd pair, fst pair)
  where pair = split (tail xs)
```

But you should be using a fold:

```
split :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
split = foldr (\x (ys, zs) -> (x : zs, ys)) ([], [])
```

Comment: That code doesn't do what he asked for, and it is also bad because it uses `head` and `tail` instead of pattern matching.

Comment: Could you give an example of an input where my code gives the wrong result, please. (And are you referring to the recursion-and-guards version or the foldr version?) I agree that pattern matching would be better than `head` and `tail`, but the OP seems to want to use guards, which --- **in this case** --- precludes pattern matching (there is nothing left to guard after the pattern match).

Comment: Sorry, I take that back about it being wrong.  Not enough coffee. :)

Answer (score 3):

The Haskell [Blow Your Mind](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Blow_your_mind) wiki, has some one liners:

```
-- splitting in two (alternating)
-- "1234567" -> ("1357", "246")

-- the lazy match with ~ is necessary for efficiency, especially enabling
-- processing of infinite lists
foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[])

(map snd *** map snd) . partition (even . fst) . zip [0..]

transpose . unfoldr (\a -> toMaybe (null a) (splitAt 2 a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two alternative versions:

```
split = conv . map (map snd) . groupWith (even.fst) . zip [0..] where
  conv [xs,ys] = (xs,ys)

split xs = (ti even xs, ti odd xs) where
  ti f = map snd . filter (f.fst) . zip [0..]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the last clause. You have to get results from recursive call and then add first and second elements to them.

```
split :: [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
split xs | length(xs) == 0 = ([],[])
         | length(xs) == 1 = (xs !! 0 : [],[])
         | length(xs) == 2 = (xs !! 0 : [], xs !! 1 : [])
         | otherwise = let (fst, snd) = split(drop 2 xs) in
                     (xs !! 0 : fst, xs !! 1 : snd)
```

Comment: This is still a horrible way to write this function.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. But I'm trying to follow question 'to accomplish this recursively(with guards) and only using the single argument xs'

Comment: You can still do that and get O(n) complexity instead of O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for some alternate way to do this, below is one such implementation:

```
split xs = 
     let (a,b) = partition (odd . snd) (zip xs [1..]) 
     in ( (map fst a), (map fst b))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a simple solution:**

By taking a list [a] we are able to split it in two new list, first we start off by declaring what happens with a empty list, here you can choose between returning an error "Empty list" or just returning two empty list as shown below, in the case of one element in list we split it in one containing x and one empty list ([x],[ ]). In cases with list size > 1 we calculate n (length of the list "divided by" 2), then we 'take' the first n elements in a new list and 'drop' the n elements from the original list xs.

```
split :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
split [] = ([],[])
split [x] = ([x],[])
split xs = (take n xs, drop n xs)
    where n = (length xs) `div` 2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the other answers the question has, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.