# Haskell: changing data type of each element in list

Tags: haskell

Yesterday, I asked a question about generating a tuple of lists: [Haskell: create a tuple of lists from an input list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685978/haskell-create-a-tuple-of-lists-from-an-input-list)

Now, I have been attempting to alter the input elements of my list [a] as they are getting put into their corresponding lists in the output tuple.

I have a manual data type of:

```
data itemRank = itemRank Int Item
```

Where I want ranks to be assigned to each item. I want the ranks to be assigned to be 1 for each of the first 4 elements of [a], 2 for the next 4 elements of [a], 3 for the next, etc.
So if:

[a] = ["apple","banana","orange","cat","dog","horse","grape","peach"]

then my output would be:

```
( [itemRank 1 "apple", itemRank 2 "dog"], ["itemRank 1 "banana", itemRank 2 "horse"], ["itemRank 1 "orange", itemRank 2 "grape"],  ["itemRank 1 "cat", itemRank 2 "peach"] )
```

Would it be easier to first output the tuple of lists using the ideas from my previous post, and then alter each element in each list within the tuple? I have been trying to do it all in one but haven't been successful. Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a data constructor and type constructor should start with an uppercase, so you define your `ItemRank` with:

```
type Item = String
data ItemRank = ItemRank Int Item deriving Show
```

You can construct `ItemRank`s for a list of `String`s with with a [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=zipWith) approach. For example:

```
Prelude> zipWith ItemRank [1..] ["Apple", "Dog"]
[ItemRank 1 "Apple",ItemRank 2 "Dog"]
```

I think you indeed better first pre-process the items to 4-tuple, and then perform a `zipWith` expression for all the items. This thus looks like:

```
someFunc :: [Item] -> (ItemRank, ItemRank, ItemRank, ItemRank)
someFunc xs = let (a, b, c, d) = toFour xs in (f a, f b, f c, f d)
    where f = zipWith ItemRank [1..]
```

or more elegant with lenses of the [**`lens`** package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens):

```
import Control.Lens((&), (%~))
import Control.Lens.Each(each)

someFunc :: [Item] -> (ItemRank, ItemRank, ItemRank, ItemRank)
someFunc xs = toFour xs & each %~ zipWith ItemRank [1..]
```

This then gives us:

```
Prelude Control.Lens Control.Lens.Each> someFunc ["apple","banana","orange","cat","dog","horse","grape","peach"]
([ItemRank 1 "apple",ItemRank 2 "dog"],[ItemRank 1 "banana",ItemRank 2 "horse"],[ItemRank 1 "orange",ItemRank 2 "grape"],[ItemRank 1 "cat",ItemRank 2 "peach"])
```